# ArcGIS Server 10.1 too slow to generate cache tiles

Tags: arcgis-server

I want to define the zoom level scale for my arcgis web map, but it seems that I should build the cache tiles first. I have waited for 2 hours but the cache status is still maintain in 0%.
I was wondering if this is normal? thanks.

[image: 0% of the tiles are available for this service]

Comment: Also, in the provided image, the column "In Progress" has no status in each of the rows cell. Is that also normal?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the caching process can be very time consuming. I have created tile cache's using ArcGIS Server 10.0.x and have encountered several problems including slow processing.

Known bottlenecks:
ArcSDE and
Disk speed (RPM) of the cache destination

I recommend to cache only a few layers at a time and afterwards place the layers into one cache folder.
Use MSD-s instead of MXD-s. The faster your map draws, the faster you’ll see tiles created.
Turn off the option for indexing in your cache folder.
Do not allow other processes access the hard disk you're writing your cache to.
Avoid having other services running while you are caching.

For more recommendations take a look at [this post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/03/22/map-caching-tips-and-best-practices-with-arcgis-server-10/)!

Comment: Thanks for your advice! However, I am not so sure what do you mean of making cache of few layers at a time. Did you mean I choose the scale = 250000 first, after generated a cache folder (probably C:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgiscache\BASEMAP), then move this folder to somewhere and choose the cache scale for 125000?

Comment: Yes. Actually you don't have to move the tiles. If you leave the output folder the same then different scales are generated into subfolders like \Layers\_alllayers\L00. Just try to generate less levels a a time.

Comment: What i meant by 'afterwards place the layers into one cache folder' was that we have used different machines (and hard drives) for creating tiles. Then you can afterwards merge the subfolders onto one drive.

Comment: I have the same issue. it was kindda inconsistent in my case. My raster layer would start caching right away even though it could take long. the "In progress" section would be doing something immediately after publishing. But for my vector layer, it just sits there doing nothing. I checked the cache directory, and nothing is being generated.